# Show excerpt in TextView

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have `ListView` with items. Is it possible to show part(excerpt like in php and html) from text in `TextView` and then when user click on item to open new activity with full text?
This is the textview in listview item - Activity A. I pass this to Activity B via intent

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="" />
```

It's normal xml nothing special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `android:maxLength="25"`
Change `25` to your value/

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure whether this is what you want, 
You can use `setSingleLine()` and `setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt where)` to make the text view show in single line and if the text lenght is more than what specified, it will put "..." at behind.

Hope that this will help you.

Comment: Thank you but I'm not sure where to put this?